# How to disable drafts?

Tags: posts, customization, draft

Using Wordpress 3.1 is it possible to completely disable the drafts functionality or at least remove the "Save Draft" button from the post screen?

Comment: i dont think there is a way to disable drafts you may be able to hook into a function to remove the save draft button and links but to completely disable it i dont think this is possible.

Comment: Also if your worried about your users adding drafts note that only contributors and above can do this not subscribers.

Comment: No, out subscribers definelty have draft option... maybe this is because i'm using custom post types?

Comment: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type#Arguments go here and add the capabilities you want that are required for a user to be able to post, etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If by draft, you mean "autosave", you can consider using this plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-feature-disable/

If you want to disable revisions, instead...try this:

```
define('WP_POST_REVISIONS', 'false');
```

You can put that in your /wp-config.php file and it should immediately take effect. Any previously saved revisions in your database will need to be purged. You can do it by running the following MySQL query in phpMyAdmin:

```
DELETE FROM wp_posts WHERE post_type = "revision";
```

Comment: Hmmm, revisions is a good idea too (but only if I can do it for specific roles). But I definitely mean drafts too - I don't want users thinking they can save lots of drafts (We only have a small server atm!)

Comment: well considering that a post barely takes up any room. You should not worry about size.

Comment: i'm thinking more about media uploads. even our editors tend to upload the same media several times :(

Answer (score 2):

I also needed this,
what I did is hiding it with a custom css :

```
#minor-publishing {display:none;}
```

and here is how to link your css to the admin space :
[How do I load a CSS style into WordPress admin area only?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44135/how-do-i-load-a-css-style-into-wordpress-admin-area-only)

EDIT:
I forgot to say, I combined this solution with :

```
wp_deregister_script('autosave');
```

to disable the autosave function (this is what the plugin mentioned above does)