# How do I load a CSS style into WordPress admin area only?

Tags: admin, css

I'm trying to load a CSS file for my WordPress post area, but having no luck. I have read over the wp_enqueue_style function and came up with the code below, but it doesn't load up. Is there a tag or character missing from my code. I have a custom write panel when a user post that I want to style with the CSS file. Any help would be great.

Here is what I have in my themes `functions.php` file:

```
function mytheme_add_init() {
    $file_dir=get_bloginfo('template_directory');
    wp_enqueue_style("functions", $file_dir."/scripts/custom.css", false, "1.0", "all");
    wp_enqueue_script("rm_script", $file_dir."/scripts/custom.js", false, "1.0");
}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just hook your callback into `admin_print_styles`, i.e.:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles', 'mytheme_add_init' );
```

Alternately, you could add an `is_admin()` conditional wrapper inside your callback, and hook into `wp_enqueue_scripts`:

```
function mytheme_add_init() {
    if ( is_admin() ) {
        $file_dir=get_bloginfo('template_directory');
        wp_enqueue_style("functions", $file_dir."/scripts/custom.css", false, "1.0", "all");
        wp_enqueue_script("rm_script", $file_dir."/scripts/custom.js", false, "1.0");
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'mytheme_add_init' );
```

But the absolute *best* approach is to **hook into your Theme's admin page**, via `admin_print_styles-appearance_page_{pagename}`:

```
add_action( 'admin_print_styles-appearance_page_{pagename}', 'mytheme_add_init', 11 );
```

This is a custom hook *specifically* for your appearance page, as defined via your `add_theme_page()` call.

Answer (score 7):

*Late answer: As both previous answers showed old, incomplete or complicated ways, here's an updated version that works the v3.5+ way.*

#### What's different?

Here's the list

- The first thing we do is using the `admin_enqueue_scripts` hook. This hook
- The `wp_enqueue_style()`s last argument is the targeted media and it's already set to `all` per default. No need to add it.
- We use the `get_template_directory_uri()` function to retrieve the URl for our stylesheet. No need to check the option value for `template_directory` here.
- We then use the return value of `get_template_directory()` to retrieve the path and wrap it into a `filemtime()` call to get the last time where the stylesheet was edited. This way we append a new version number as query argument and force browser to reload the stylesheet if there's a new version. No need to force hard reloads with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>.
- One important thing is to add the right dependencies as you don't want to have your styles overwritten with a higher specifity by `wp-admin.css`, `ie` (even worse) or the color scheme. The really tough part is to check the color scheme, as this file carries most of what is styled in the admin UI and is a user setting. We want to add this as dependency as well.
- The last thing we do is wrapping the call to add the hook into another function that is hooked to the contextual `admin_head-*` hook, where `*` is the pageslug. We hook it two times to take new as well as edited posts into consideration.

Here's the code for your `functions.php` file.

```
add_action( 'admin_head-post.php', 'wpse44135AttachAdminStyle' );
add_action( 'admin_head-post-new.php', 'wpse44135AttachAdminStyle' );
function wpse44135AttachAdminStyle()
{
    add_action( 'admin_enqueue_scripts', 'wpse44135EnqueueAdminStyle' );
}
function wpse44135EnqueueAdminStyle()
{
    $scheme = get_user_meta(
        get_current_user_id(),
        'admin_color',
        true
    );

    wp_enqueue_style(
        "admin_style",
        get_template_directory_uri()."/scripts/custom.css",
        array( 'wp-admin', 'ie', "colors-{$scheme}" ),
        filemtime( get_template_directory()."/scripts/custom.css" ),
        "all"
    );
}
```

### Alternatives?

In case you just want to add styles to the TinyMCE WYSIWYG editor, you can use [`add_editor_style()`](http://queryposts.com/function/add_editor_style/) to register your themes stylesheet in the admin areas text editor as well. The path you add as argument is relative to your themes root. In your `functions.php` file:

```
add_editor_style( '/scripts/custom.css' );
```

It's as simple as that.

Comment: I get a "Fatal error: Cannot redeclare wpse44135_enqueue_admin_style() (previously declared " when trying this.

Comment: @songdogtech "Cannot redeclare" explains that a function, method, etc. was already _declared_/set. Problem _was_ that I used the same function name twice. For the future: Please just google plain PHP errors and file and [edit]. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't know how to fix the error, that's what I commented.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a quick way to add some style in admin head. hope this helps:

```
add_action('admin_head', 'my_custom_fonts');
function my_custom_fonts() {
  echo '<style>
    body, td, textarea, input, select {
    font-family: "Lucida Grande";
    font-size: 12px;
  } 
</style>';
}
```