# modify stylesheet of a particular page inside wp-admin

Tags: css

inside this path, are the listing of my wordpress pages.

```
/wp-admin/edit.php?post_type=page&orderby=title&order=asc
```

i want to remove the default `<table>` design of the page and create my own style.
how do i go and modify that particular page.

Does this function `add_action()` still applicable? only to a particular page?

or should i modify the `edit.php` directly?

Answer (score 0):

Do not modify the edit.php file directly as modifying WordPress core files are not recommended  and may generate new issues, will get overwritten when WordPress is updated.

Instead you can use properties and functions of [WP_List_Table](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_List_Table) class to change it, along with [adding css to backend](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44135/how-do-i-load-a-css-style-into-wordpress-admin-area-only) for design changes.