# How to place HTML below the title of the (custom) post overview

Tags: posts, customization, wp-admin, hooks

<sub>**Edit:** Yes, I know, I provided an answer to this question myself. However, I'm still interested in other solutions and/or comments on the one I found. Is this how you would do this? Are there any other ways?</sub>

---

I would like to provide some additional description and on-page help (i.e., no contextual help or help tabs) on the overview page (i.e., `edit.php`) for a custom post type.

According to `edit.php` (as well as `class-wp-list-table.php` and `class-wp-posts-list-table.php`) there is no appropriate hook.

So, how can I do this?

A few notes:

- I came up with a solution, which I would describe *a bit hackish*, so I'm open for a *clean* solution (if there is one);
- I will post my solution as an answer so you can comment on that (and so the question and answer are kept separate);
- I'm aware that I can do this via JavaScript/jQuery - but that's not *clean* (IMO) as well...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I kind of feel like I'm missing something obvious, but maybe I'm not. What about the [`admin_notices`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/admin_notices) hook, seems like the obvious choice to me. There are some admin CSS classes available you can use, like `updated`, `error` or `update-nag`, or you can of course add your own styles, like asked and answered [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/44135/22534) or [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/1058/22534).

**Code:**

```
<?php
function my_cpt_info() {
    if ('edit-my_cpt' === get_current_screen()->id) {
        ?>
        <div class="updated">
            <p>
                <?php _e('Some information about my CPT...', 'my-text-domain'); ?>
            </p>
        </div>
        <?php
    }
} // function my_cpt_info
add_action('admin_notices', 'my_cpt_info');
?>
```

Comment: Well, I honestly didn't think of the admin notices - simply because they are handled outside from where I looked. You are, of course, right, and this is the obvious hook/place. One problem, however, is plugins/settings that restrict (or hide etc.) admin notices for specific user( role)s. Anyway, +1, and thanks for taking care of this question.

Comment: My pleasure. You might be right about the restrictions/interferences by plugins, but I guess you'll have to deal with that if it actually is occurring. The only thing else I've in mind is, there is the hook `all_admin_notices`, which might not as well known or at least not as widely used. @tf

Answer (score 1):

Currently, I'm doing this:

- hijack the bulk update message;
- adjust the count for *update*;
- insert my text;
- hook with 0 priority.

In code, this reads as follows:

```
function my_cpt_info($messages) {
    if ('edit-my_cpt' === get_current_screen()->id) {
        global $bulk_counts;
        $bulk_counts['updated'] = 1;

        if (! is_array($messages))
            $messages = array();

        $messages['my_cpt']['updated'] = 'Whatever it is that I need to explain about this post type, I just do it right here...<br>';

        return $messages;
    }
} // function my_cpt_info
add_filter('bulk_post_updated_messages', 'my_cpt_info', 0);
```