# How to remove default style of header in wordpress metabox

Tags: plugin-development, css, html

I have the problem which when I create a header in my wordpress plugin metabox, it always apply the default style on my header: 
[image]

even when I apply, my own style, `<h3 style="background-color: black; color:blue">Text Block Settings</h3>`, it only changes the text color but not the background color, why??
[image]

Comment: Take a look at this [answer](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/85688/22534).